# i can't get the list from php I've checked it thoroughly and everything is same

Tags: php

this is my code,I've made connection using

```
<?php include("Includes/db.php"); ?>
```

and it is working well but i don't know why im not getting my list products from categories cat_title.here you can see my php code for getting the products name/title.

```
<tr align="center">
   <td>Product Category :</td>
   <td>
      <select name="product_cat">
        <option>Select a Category</option>
          <?php 
       $get_cats = "SELECT * FROM categories";

       $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

       while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats))
       {
         $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
         $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title']; 

         echo "<option>$cat_title</option>";
       }
          ?>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

[in the categories table data is coming from cat_title.
 i checked my ecommerce database too but still not getting the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUvpd.png)

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: If you want to make use of the selected option once you get the list working you need it to look something like this `echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";` Without a value attribute they are not much use

Comment: Unfortunately what you show us looks like it should work. So your problem is something else or somewhere else in your code.

Comment: well it's working now thank you :) but the code I've used in my page is only this one